# Visual Studio won't show last build

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm doing a C# WinForms application in VS2013 and no matter what change I make in the code or form, when i build and run it it shows e the first build (empty form with no code)
All the solutions i've found online didnt helped:
I closed all instances of VS.
I deleted /bin and /obj folders and rebuild.
I did clean solution and rebuild.
I deleted the Temp folder from the user AppData folder.
I unchecked "only build startup project and dependencies on run".
I resstarted the computer.
None of which worked. any ideas?

Comment: Once it's launched, check the path of the executable (via task manager)

Comment: GrantWinney a single project solution.

Comment: SimonMᶜKenzie the path is the bin folder.